# Error in uploading lambda"Unable to export project to jar"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to use the Eclipse Java Toolkit. I followed the instructions on the AWS website ([User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/getting-started.html)) to install Eclipse and the Toolkit.

I was following [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-aws-lambda).

When I am trying to upload lambda then I keep getting the following error.

Stack trace:

```
Message: Failed to upload project to Lambda
Exception Stack Trace: 
com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.exceptions.AwsActionException
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.UploadFunctionWizard.doFinish(UploadFunctionWizard.java:115)
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.plugin.AbstractAwsJobWizard$1.run(AbstractAwsJobWizard.java:35)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.util.UploadFunctionUtil.performFunctionUpload(UploadFunctionUtil.java:82)
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.UploadFunctionWizard.doFinish(UploadFunctionWizard.java:111)
... 2 more
```

Comment: Which version of Java you are using ?

Comment: Java 9 is installed in my machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please uninstall your java 10 and install java 8

Checkout this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) for supported runtime in lambda.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. It appears that it was rooted from the incompatibility among the following three things:

1. jdk version - as indicated above, java8, jave11. In my case, jdk 1.8.231 works, jdk1.8.144 failed
2. Eclipse version - best to explicitly set vm to be used in the eclipse.ini file. Both older or newer version could fail. In my case, 2018-09 works, but Kepler (older) and 2019-12 (newer) failed
3. AWS Toolkit for Eclipse version - the current version as of this writing (1/11/2020)

Also, everything is 64 bit (choose the proper download file), in Windows 10.

It was indeed frustrating to trial-and-error different combinations just to helloworld, and the valid combinations may evolve over time as newer versions come along. Hope my direction on the causes is not too far off. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I had also shared the same issue while uploading the lambda function to AWS via eclipse, and the issue was resolved by changing the java jdk version to 1.8, previously i was using jdk11 but installing to java8 and changing to the right library in the project build path resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used Eclipse Version 2019_12.  I first downloaded the latest (2021_06 at the time).  It requires java 11.  However the AWS plugin had a bug which prevented me from using the framework. It looks like this is a known bug and Eclipse is working on a fix. Also, DON'T upgrade your eclipse.  When I upgraded the AWS framework was disabled because the upgrade changed the version of Eclipse that was not compatible. Here is the AWS compatibility list as of September 04, 2021.  Version 2019_12 worked for me and no issues.

[image: AWS plugin compatibility with Eclipse]